# Is it possible to capture the video frames when using the Google Hangouts API?

Tags: api, google-plus, video-capture, video-processing

I would like to use the Hangouts API to try to capture the video frames and process them to see if I could begin writing an app to measure average brightness over the entire frame or a sub-frame.

Is it possible to pull the frame itself and measure pixel data like this? Is there any command in the Hangouts API that allows for this, or is there other third-party software that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get direct access to the video feed or video frame data in the Hangouts API.